# Flask-Swagger-UI does not recognize path to swagger.json

Tags: flask, swagger-ui, flask-restful

I'm building an API, using Flask and flask-restful and flask-swagger-ui. I have now modified the project structure and now I can no longer access the project's swagger.json file.

Based on the package documentation [flask-swagger-ui](https://github.com/sveint/flask-swagger-ui), you would only need to change the parameter API_URL to the correct path. But even when entering relative path or full path, I can no longer access the file.

[image]

**My Code**:

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify
from flask_migrate import Migrate
from flask_restful import Api
from flask_swagger_ui import get_swaggerui_blueprint

def create_app(config_name):

    app = Flask(__name__)

    app.config.from_object(config[config_name])

    api = Api(app, prefix="/api/v1")

    '''swagger specific'''
    SWAGGER_URL = '/api/v1/docs'
    # API_URL = 'templates/swagger.json'
    API_URL = 'app/templates/docs/swagger.json'
    SWAGGERUI_BLUEPRINT = get_swaggerui_blueprint(
        SWAGGER_URL,
        API_URL,
        config={
            'app_name': "My Rest App"
        }
    )

    app.register_blueprint(SWAGGERUI_BLUEPRINT, url_prefix=SWAGGER_URL)

    db.init_app(app)
    Migrate(app, db)

    return app
```

**My Tree Structure:**

```
├── API
│   ├── app
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── models
│   │   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   │   ├── db.py  
│   │   │   └── db2.py
│   │   ├── routes
│   │   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   │   ├── resources.py
│   │   └── templates
│   │       └── docs
│   │           └── swagger.json
│   ├── app.db
│   ├── config.py
│   ├── main.py
│   ├── migrations
│   ├── requeriments
│   └── tests
└── README.md
```

I need help, to understand the problem of the path to the file and thus correct the problem.

Comment: Did anyone ever figure this out?

Comment: @vic.py  Did you find any solution ?

Answer (score 7):

I believe that its a restriction on flask's end, but it seems like you *must* place static files in a folder explicitly named `static/` at the root of your flask app.

Try changing

```
API_URL = 'app/templates/docs/swagger.json'
```

to

```
API_URL = '/static/swagger.json'
```

Then create a `static/` folder in `API/app/`, and move your json into it. Like so: `API/app/static/swagger.json`

If that doesn't work, make sure you have the `static/` folder in the correct directory, try `print(app.root_path)` after defining your flask app variable in order to see what flask considered the root path to be.

Comment: It's also necessary to include the leading '/' in the API_URL

Answer (score 2):

We can't provide any custom file path for swagger.json.

But there is one catch which we can do if you require.
I was facing the same issue where I need to provide different prefix for swagger URL and swagger.json.
If we just want to serve swagger.json file from a different prefix instead of '/static/swagger.json':

Then make changes as below:

```
APP = Flask(__name__, static_url_path = '/my-prefix/static')
API_URL = '/my-prefix/static/swagger.json'
```

Answer (score 0):

For me "root_path" solved the problem,

Lets say I have the following path:

"C:\script\mycode\src\swagger.json"

```
def resource_path(relative_path):
    base_path = getattr(
        sys,
        '_MEIPASS',
        os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
    return os.path.join(base_path, relative_path)

new_path = resource_path("swagger.json")
new_path = new_path.replace("swagger.json", "")
app = Flask(__name__, root_path=new_path, static_folder="")

print("app.root_path ===================>>",app.root_path)
#prints: "C:\script\mycode\src\"

app.register_blueprint(get_swaggerui_blueprint(
    '/api/swagger',
    "\\swagger.json",   #put starting slash even the app.root_path ends with 
                         #slash. and check in "app.root_path" if additional path 
                         #need to be added with "\\swagger.json"
    config=apiConfig),
    url_prefix=apiPrefixV1+'swagger',
    name='v1')
```

Note: For me resource path is used for pyinstaller build. For local test also works fine!